# Accordion style menu active depending on url segment

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, accordion, user-experience

I have been puzzling over this one for days. The idea is to replicate Outlook 2010 style sidebar navigation and create a UX that is familiar to our users. I currently use this for basic navigation and active state on url.

```
<ul class="fltrt" style="padding-right:5px;"> 
<?php foreach($NavigationArray as $i =>     $nav_item): ?> 
<li <?php if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == $i ): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>> 
<?= anchor($i, $nav_item) ?> </li> <?php endforeach ?> </ul>
```

I just wish to implement a simple accordion menu using http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ as an example, the section heading are the tile and the menu loops down like above, BUT, if the first segment of the url = the heading is active, and if the link in the accordion menu matches the second segment of the url it is also active.

Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<li <?php if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == $i ): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
```

won't work.

`$this->uri->uri_string()` will be something like `/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction` and `$i` is probably an int (0, 1, 2, 3) so they will never be equal.

You want to match `$this->uri->segment(n);` where n is the segment of the url you want to match. e.g. if the url is `/index.php/home/overview` and the menu item you want to match is 'home`, you'd do

```
<li <?php if ( $this->uri->segment(1) == $nav_item ): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
```